# Internet Explorer Float Display Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am struggling with the header of a website template displaying in Internet Explorer.

http://www.furnituremind.co.uk

The search field and button are not in the same place on IE8+ but are in every other browser. I have tried everything and researched issues with IE float CSS property but can not make any progress.

Do I need to specify a completely different CSS sheet for IE8 just to get it positioned properly?

Comment: If normal CSS doesn't work, you'll have to resort to a conditional stylesheet. Google the term.

Comment: Fix your validation errors:   http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.furnituremind.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is, instead of floating the nav right, position the nav absolute.  Set top and right properties to adjust where you want it to line up.

see jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kuT9K/1/